# Want to fetch data from three tables in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a little query in which I need your help, Please have a look below.

I want to fetch all the data from the products table with some conditions like city, price, Type, category.
I can fetch all the data but I can't fetch the category data from the product model with all other conditions.

Below is my tables and Eloquent relations. I am using Laravel 5.2.

```
products ->foreign_key('subcategory_id')
subcategories ->foreign_key('category_id')
category
users: ->foreign_key('product_id')
users table columns: ->city, price, product_id
```

Relations:

```
User Model:
public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

Product Model:
public function subcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory', 'subcategory_id');
}


Subcategory Model:
public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'subcategory_id');
}
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}


Category Model:
public function subCategory(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
}

public function product(){
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Subcategory');
}
```

Here is my query(in ProductsController.php).

```
$city_id, $category_id, $min_price, $max_price : demo data passed

//fetching city data
$products = Product::whereHas('user', function($query) use($city_id) {
     $query->where('city_id', $city_id);
});

//fetching category data (I am not sure about this part)
$products =  $products->whereHas('category', function($query) use($category_id) {
    $query->where('id', $category_id);
});

//fetching price data
$products = $products->where('price', '>=', $min_price)->where('price', '<=', $max_price);

//sub category filtering
$products = $products->where('subcategory_id', 1);


$products = $products->get()->toArray();

return $products;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `with()` method:

Product Model:Add the following method

```
public function subcategory($category_id){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory', 'subcategory_id')->with(`category`)->where('category_id',$category_id);
}
```

Now in Controller, you can check if the product belongs to that category,

```
$products = $products->subcategory($category_id);
```

This will get you category data also.

Comment: there is a error.
 Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::parseWithRelations() must be of the type array, null given, called in F:\xampp\htdocs\projectName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1028 and defined

Comment: Ok.. I don't have my laravel setup with me.. will get back to you by 5:30.. If you could post the error I will try to check

Comment: `category` I have used back ticks instead of '' try replacing them

Comment: return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory', 'subcategory_id')->with(**`category`**)->where('category_id',$category_id);

Comment: There is still error.  FatalErrorException in Model.php line 797:
Class 'Ap‌​p\Subcategory' not found

Comment: that means you do not have model in that namespace

Comment: could you check where is your Subcategory model and what is its namespace

Comment: my model is in App directory and beow is my subcategory model code.

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public function product(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'subcategory_id');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}

Comment: hi, when i replace the back ticks with single quotes, then it doesn't give any error only blank array shown. but when i print the query it shows the collections. does it make some sense. i am stuck here from last three days, please take a look. @jaisingkar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121180/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-rahul-mangal).

Comment: sure i am waiting you there