# Fetch records from three distant related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a little query in which I need your help, Please take a below look.

Below is my tables and Eloquent relations. I am using Laravel 5.2.

```
products {id, subcategory_id}
subcategories {id, category_id}
category {id, name}


Product Model:
public function subcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory', 'subcategory_id');
}


Subcategory Model:
public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'subcategory_id');
}
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}


Category Model:
public function subCategory(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
}

public function product(){
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Subcategory');
}
```

How can I fetch all the records from a particular category using category_id.

Thanks For your help.

Comment: you can use joins for that.

Comment: can't figure out, try it many times, can you post it here

Comment: $products = Category::findOrFail($category_id)->product;

Comment: ok i got it, thanks, but i used it with some conditions, here is the link of my full questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991368/want-to-fetch-data-from-three-tables-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: @RahulMangal do you want to get all the products which belongs to category_id ?

Comment: yes, but i also need to check some other conditions please see this questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991368/want-to-fetch-data-from-three-tables-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: @RahulMangal I just checked your other question, could you check if that's the answer you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may solve your issue

```
 $products = DB::table("products")
->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.id', '=', 'products.subcategory_id')
->join('category ', 'category.id', '=', 'subcategories .category_id')
->get();
```

Comment: Your code works brother. hats off.
but can we do it using Eloquent method, as i used only eloquent in whole project